# Kitchen list using Docker Desktop not launching

Tags: chef-infra, kitchen-dokken

I'm trying to configure test kitchen using Docker Desktop but some how its not launching.

kitchen list command just timed out.

PS C:\chef-repo\cookbooks\apache> kitchen list
C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/docker-api-2.2.0/lib/docker/connection.rb:91:in `rescue in request': connect_write timeout reached (Docker::Error::TimeoutError) from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/docker-api-2.2.0/lib/docker/connection.rb:44:in` request'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/docker-api-2.2.0/lib/docker/connection.rb:109:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Connection>' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/docker-api-2.2.0/lib/docker/connection.rb:114:in` info'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/docker-api-2.2.0/lib/docker.rb:114:in `info' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/kitchen-dokken-2.19.1/lib/kitchen/helpers.rb:122:in` docker_info'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/kitchen-dokken-2.19.1/lib/kitchen/driver/dokken.rb:48:in `<class:Dokken>' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/kitchen-dokken-2.19.1/lib/kitchen/driver/dokken.rb:36:in` module:Driver'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/kitchen-dokken-2.19.1/lib/kitchen/driver/dokken.rb:32:in `<module:Kitchen>'         from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/kitchen-dokken-2.19.1/lib/kitchen/driver/dokken.rb:31:in` <top (required)>'
from internal:C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require' from <internal:C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in` require'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/plugin.rb:35:in `load' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/driver.rb:37:in` for_plugin'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:235:in `new_driver' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:250:in` new_instance'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:143:in `block in build_instances' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:142:in` map'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:142:in `with_index' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:142:in` build_instances'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:116:in `instances' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/command.rb:109:in` filtered_instances'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/command.rb:139:in `parse_subcommand' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/command/list.rb:29:in` call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:52:in `perform' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:120:in` list'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in` invoke_command'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in` start'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/bin/kitchen:11:in `block in <top (required)>' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/errors.rb:183:in` with_friendly_errors'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/bin/kitchen:11:in `<top (required)>' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/bin/kitchen:413:in` load'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/bin/kitchen:413:in `<main>' C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:307:in` select_with_timeout': connect_write timeout reached (Excon::Error::Timeout)
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:153:in `rescue in block in connect' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:134:in` block in connect'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/resolv.rb:111:in `each_address' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/resolv.rb:58:in` each_address'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:124:in `connect' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:51:in` initialize'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:476:in `new' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:476:in` socket'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:121:in `request_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/redirect_follower.rb:15:in` request_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/mock.rb:57:in `request_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/instrumentor.rb:34:in` request_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:19:in `request_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:22:in` request_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:22:in `request_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:22:in` request_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:286:in `request' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:50:in` error_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in `error_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in` error_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in `error_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:315:in` rescue in request'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:230:in `request' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:50:in` error_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in `error_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in` error_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in `error_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:315:in` rescue in request'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:230:in `request' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:50:in` error_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in `error_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in` error_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in `error_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:315:in` rescue in request'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:230:in `request' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/docker-api-2.2.0/lib/docker/connection.rb:45:in` request'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/docker-api-2.2.0/lib/docker/connection.rb:109:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Connection>' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/docker-api-2.2.0/lib/docker/connection.rb:114:in` info'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/docker-api-2.2.0/lib/docker.rb:114:in `info' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/kitchen-dokken-2.19.1/lib/kitchen/helpers.rb:122:in` docker_info'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/kitchen-dokken-2.19.1/lib/kitchen/driver/dokken.rb:48:in `<class:Dokken>' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/kitchen-dokken-2.19.1/lib/kitchen/driver/dokken.rb:36:in` module:Driver'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/kitchen-dokken-2.19.1/lib/kitchen/driver/dokken.rb:32:in `<module:Kitchen>'         from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/kitchen-dokken-2.19.1/lib/kitchen/driver/dokken.rb:31:in` <top (required)>'
from internal:C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require' from <internal:C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in` require'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/plugin.rb:35:in `load' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/driver.rb:37:in` for_plugin'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:235:in `new_driver' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:250:in` new_instance'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:143:in `block in build_instances' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:142:in` map'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:142:in `with_index' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:142:in` build_instances'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:116:in `instances' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/command.rb:109:in` filtered_instances'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/command.rb:139:in `parse_subcommand' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/command/list.rb:29:in` call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:52:in `perform' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:120:in` list'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in` invoke_command'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in` start'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/bin/kitchen:11:in `block in <top (required)>' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/errors.rb:183:in` with_friendly_errors'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/bin/kitchen:11:in `<top (required)>' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/bin/kitchen:413:in` load'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/bin/kitchen:413:in `<main>' C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:1214:in` __connect_nonblock': A blocking operation is currently executing. - connect(2) would block (IO::EINPROGRESSWaitWritable)
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:1214:in `connect_nonblock' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:147:in` block in connect'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/resolv.rb:111:in `each_address' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/resolv.rb:58:in` each_address'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:124:in `connect' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:51:in` initialize'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:476:in `new' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:476:in` socket'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:121:in `request_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/redirect_follower.rb:15:in` request_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/mock.rb:57:in `request_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/instrumentor.rb:34:in` request_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:19:in `request_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:22:in` request_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:22:in `request_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:22:in` request_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:286:in `request' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:50:in` error_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in `error_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in` error_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in `error_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:315:in` rescue in request'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:230:in `request' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:50:in` error_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in `error_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in` error_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in `error_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:315:in` rescue in request'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:230:in `request' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:50:in` error_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in `error_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in` error_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in `error_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:315:in` rescue in request'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:230:in `request' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/docker-api-2.2.0/lib/docker/connection.rb:45:in` request'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/docker-api-2.2.0/lib/docker/connection.rb:109:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Connection>' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/docker-api-2.2.0/lib/docker/connection.rb:114:in` info'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/docker-api-2.2.0/lib/docker.rb:114:in `info' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/kitchen-dokken-2.19.1/lib/kitchen/helpers.rb:122:in` docker_info'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/kitchen-dokken-2.19.1/lib/kitchen/driver/dokken.rb:48:in `<class:Dokken>' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/kitchen-dokken-2.19.1/lib/kitchen/driver/dokken.rb:36:in` module:Driver'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/kitchen-dokken-2.19.1/lib/kitchen/driver/dokken.rb:32:in `<module:Kitchen>'         from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/kitchen-dokken-2.19.1/lib/kitchen/driver/dokken.rb:31:in` <top (required)>'
from internal:C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require' from <internal:C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in` require'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/plugin.rb:35:in `load' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/driver.rb:37:in` for_plugin'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:235:in `new_driver' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:250:in` new_instance'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:143:in `block in build_instances' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:142:in` map'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:142:in `with_index' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:142:in` build_instances'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:116:in `instances' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/command.rb:109:in` filtered_instances'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/command.rb:139:in `parse_subcommand' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/command/list.rb:29:in` call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:52:in `perform' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:120:in` list'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in` invoke_command'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in` start'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/bin/kitchen:11:in `block in <top (required)>' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/lib/kitchen/errors.rb:183:in` with_friendly_errors'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-3.5.0/bin/kitchen:11:in `<top (required)>' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/bin/kitchen:413:in` load'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/bin/kitchen:413:in `<main>' C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:307:in` select_with_timeout': connect_write timeout reached (Excon::Error::Timeout)
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:153:in `rescue in block in connect' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:134:in` block in connect'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/resolv.rb:111:in `each_address' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/resolv.rb:58:in` each_address'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:124:in `connect' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:51:in` initialize'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:476:in `new' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:476:in` socket'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:121:in `request_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/redirect_follower.rb:15:in` request_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/mock.rb:57:in `request_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/instrumentor.rb:34:in` request_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:19:in `request_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:22:in` request_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:22:in `request_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:22:in` request_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:286:in `request' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:50:in` error_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in `error_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in` error_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in `error_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:315:in` rescue in request'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:230:in `request' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:50:in` error_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in `error_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in` error_call'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:17:in `error_call' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:315:in` rescue in request'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/excon-0.99.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:230:in `request' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/docker-api-2.2.0/lib/docker/connection.rb:45:in` request'
from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/docker-api-2.2.0/lib/docker/connection.rb:109:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Connection>' from C:/opscode/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/docker-api-2.2.0/lib/docker/connection.rb:114:in` info'

Answer (score 0):

Within Docker Desktop go to "Settings" and enable "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS". This will expose that port so depending on your environment you may not want to do that.